# Maven causa problema com caracteres especiais para arquivos ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho um projeto no Eclipse totalmente configurado e meus arquivos .java utilizam encoding ISO-8859-1 e alguns outros arquivos de resource utilizam encoding UTF-8.

Preciso criar um archetype a partir deste projeto.

Já tentei de toda forma e não consigo fazer o Maven criar meu archetype com o encoding correto. Não importa o que eu faça, os arquivos sempre são copiados para o archetype com o encoding UTF-8.

Já tentei:

Configurar o POM.xml

```
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Passar estes parâmetros na linha de comando

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=ISO-8859-1
```

E nada funciona.

Qualquer ajuda será benvinda.

Answer (score 1):

Após procurar por todos os parâmetros possíveis, encontrei a resposta:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.encoding=ISO-8859-1
```

Funcionou para mim!